# mysqli_multi_qry wait for the output of the query before calling it again

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a code below that creates a multi qry

```
$sql_multi = "";
for ($branch_index = 0; $branch_index < count($branch_ids); $branch_index++) {
    for ($item_index = 0; $item_index < count($item_ids); $item_index++) {
        $item_id   = $item_ids[$item_index];
        $branch_id = $branch_ids[$branch_index];
        $sql_multi .= "CALL sp_pivot_qty_eb(".$item_id.",".$branch_id.",'".$_GET["to"]."');";
    }
}

/* execute multi query for qty */
if ($con->multi_query($sql_multi)) {
    do {
        $result = $con->store_result();
        
        while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            foreach ($rows as $value) {
                echo $value . "<br>";
            }
        }
        
        $con->next_result();
    } while ($con->more_results() && $con->next_result()) ;
}
```

This code creates a query based on given branch_id and item_id. This code works but if the item_id reach 1 thousand data (equivalent on 1k stored procedure) this is the error occurs. I get a lot of sleep in my database and also timeout error.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this error? Call the query one at the time or wait for the output 1st. Any suggestion?

Here is my SP

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_pivot_qty_eb`(
    param_item_id INT,
    param_branch_id INT,
    param_date VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            param_branch_id,
            "~",
            param_item_id,
            "~",
            REPLACE(IFNULL(SUM(b.qty),0),'.00','')
        ) AS data_output
    FROM    
            dim_item_masterfile a
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                    a.item_id,
                    SUM(a.qty) AS qty 
            FROM
                            fct_inventory a
            LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_sales_payment a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_sales_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id 
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
                            
                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_sales_payment_cc a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_sales_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id  
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
                            
                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_sales_payment_gc a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_sales_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id  
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
                            
                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_sales_payment_hc a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_sales_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id  
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
                            
                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_sales_payment_flexi a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_sales_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id  
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date

                    UNION ALL

                    SELECT
                            a.appkey,
                            a.sales_date 
                    FROM
                            fct_cashin_st a
                    INNER JOIN
                            fct_cashin_item b
                    ON
                            a.appkey = b.appkey AND b.item_id = param_item_id
                    WHERE
                            a.is_void = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.is_cancel = 0 
                    AND 
                            a.branch_id = param_branch_id  
                    AND 
                            a.sales_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
            ) b
            ON
                    a.appkey = b.appkey
            WHERE
                    IFNULL(b.sales_date,DATE(a.date_created)) BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND param_date
            AND
                    a.branch_id = param_branch_id 
            GROUP BY
                    a.item_id
    ) b
    ON
            a.id = b.item_id
    WHERE
            a.id = param_item_id
    GROUP BY
             a.id
    ORDER BY
             a.id ASC;
END
```

Comment: To be honest, I would get rid of a multi query, get rid of a stored procedure, make it a single query instead that accepts multiple parameters. Or at least get rid of a multi query as it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Without seeing what your SP does it's difficult to say what you should do or what might be the problem, but honest advice: remove multi_query and the stored procedure. Both are very old features and very difficult to get right. Calling SP from PHP is really nasty and will cause you more problems than it's worth. You can achieve a much cleaner and easier solution with prepared statements.

Comment: @dharman my sp is only find the qty based on given branch_id and item_id

Comment: im not on my PC now so I cant edit it. I am thinking instead of multi query i will make a union all. Does that approach help? Especially im going to union 3k select

Comment: @Dharman I added the SP thnx